# Configure matplotlib colorbar to match 3D surface values

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to display the result of a Fast Fourier Transform as a 3D-surface from a 2D-matrix (shape: 2048x1024) with a colorbar on the side that should match with my values.
The display works fine but the colorbar's "color" and the graph's color don't match. How should I configure the colorbar and the graph to match?

I have tried to set `vmin` and `vmax` values according to my FFT results but then the color of the graph is totally wrong.
I have also tried the function `clim(vmin, vmax)` or the method `.set_clim(vmin, vmax)` but the problem is still the same.

Here is my code:
`rp` is a 2048x1024 matrix.

```py
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


figure(2, figsize=(9.6, 7.2))
ax1 = gca(projection='3d')
X = np.arange(0, 1024)
Y = np.arange(0, 2048)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = 20 * np.log10(abs(rp))
# Plot the surface.
surf1 = ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet', antialiased=False, vmin=np.min(Z), vmax=np.max(Z))
# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
colorbar(surf1)
title('3D frequency profile')

show()
```

Here is what I get without configuring `vmin` and `vmax` values for the colorbar. The max color (red) doesn't match with the maximun pikes and the colorbar max and min value don't match with my min and max values from the graph (NB: min=-24 and max=145).

[first_figure](https://i.postimg.cc/pdsRCGfd/D058-B479-5-CDC-48-F9-A7-E3-55-B7959-E5107.png)

And here is what I get when I set `vmin` and `vmax`. All the graph is roughly the same shade whereas I should have to two pikes in red.

[second_figure](https://i.postimg.cc/rpVqSXtb/1-D340273-9-FD6-4459-8-BC4-915-D852283-E1.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: why not use [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html)? 3d plots are generally difficult to interpret.  also [JET is generally considered harmful](https://youtu.be/xAoljeRJ3lU)

Comment: @SamMason imshow displays a 2D-image that could be sufficient but my requirements ask a 3D-plots to show the power of the signal (Z axis). I have tried with different `cmap` value such as `bwr` or `PuOr` and the problem persists. Any advice for the colormap instead of `jet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the reason of my problem. The problem was the stride of the `colormap` for the graph (it's kind of the resolution of it, if I understand it well - [cstride and rstride documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots)). More precisely, it uses a surface of `cstride * rstride` to average the energy of the signal on the surface and makes the color of map correspond to this mean. My pikes were really thin that is why they were not in the good shade.
I had to specify the parameters `cstride` and `rstride` with a smaller value. As their default value was 10.

So now I have:

```py
figure(1, figsize=(12, 6))
X = np.arange(0, 1024)
Y = np.arange(0, 2048)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = 20 * np.log10(abs(rp))
mappable = cm.ScalarMappable()
mappable.set_array(Z)
suptitle('3D-plot and 2D-plot of frequency profile')
ax1 = subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=mappable.cmap, norm=mappable.norm, linewidth=0,
                 antialiased=False, cstride=10, rstride=1)
ax2 = subplot(122)
ax2.imshow(Z, cmap=mappable.cmap, norm=mappable.norm,
           extent=(np.min(X), np.max(X), np.min(Y), np.max(Y)),
           interpolation=None)
colorbar(mappable)

show()
```

NB: I could have left the default value for cstride as I only need to change the `row` stride. But it could be helpful for someone else.

And here is the result I get and it corresponds to what I want.
[image]

NB2: Be careful by reducing the stride, the bigger the input data, the slower the script.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want to use a `Mappable` stuff in Matplotlib, something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mappable = plt.cm.ScalarMappable()
mappable.set_array(Z)
```

and then call `plot_surface` with `cmap` and `norm` from that mappable, e.g:

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=mappable.cmap, norm=mappable.norm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

you can then use this mappable for the `colorbar`:

```
plt.colorbar(mappable)
```

this should use the default [`viridis` colormap](https://youtu.be/xAoljeRJ3lU) color map, but can be manually specified as:

```
mappable = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
```

Viridis is a nice "perceptually uniform" color map, see the above video for why Matlab's `jet` is almost always a bad choice, and why it's even better than it's more modern default `parula`

this just seems to be reusing the data in Z for both the "vertical" height and color, hence my suggestion of using `imshow`, e.g:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

X, Y = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(-2, 2, 128),
    np.linspace(-2, 2, 128),
)
Z = np.exp(-(X ** 2 + Y ** 2)) * 3 + 5

mappable = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
mappable.set_array(Z)
mappable.set_clim(5, 8) # optional

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=mappable.cmap, norm=mappable.norm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.imshow(Z, cmap=mappable.cmap, norm=mappable.norm, extent=(
    np.min(X), np.max(X), np.min(Y), np.max(Y)), interpolation='none')

plt.colorbar(mappable)
plt.tight_layout()
```

gives me:

[image: plot_surface vs imshow]

I find that the second non-3D plot allows me to see what's going on much more easily

Comment: I totally agree with you, I could only use the `imshow` plot. Plus I don't have any bug with it. My real problem was about the configuration of the colorbar, because the maximum color is yellow, right? So my "two" pikes on the 3D-plot should have been in yellow, but not. If I don't specify the `vmin` and `vmax` values, it looks like the maximum values are on the edge, which is wrong. So either my configuration is broken or I have a bug with matplotlib here.
Thanks for you help by the way!